# JDO vs possible programming language change

Tags: jdo

I have been thinking about using JDO in my new project. However, there is always the possibility of changing the Programming language, or rewriting / adding some modules in other languages. But i fear that in that case the data may not be accessible (parseable, understandable).

Are my fears justified?

Answer (score 0):

If you persist data using JDO to say RDBMS, then the data is held in RDBMS (in a logical well-defined structure) which is equally accessible using SQL via a different programming language. The datastore is what holds the data, not some mysterious "JDO" thing, which is simply an API to get the data there from a Java app and Java objects.